# Can you sell a liquid asset bellow market price to lower your taxes?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, germany

Imagine I bought 1 Bitcoin or any similarly liquid asset for 1.000 €. Imagine the market price went up to 10.000 €. If I sell at market value, I made a 9.000 € taxable profit.

**Is it legal to weasel out of this tax by selling the asset for 1.000 €, which is below market price?**

This is one of those questions that defy all intuition for me. It is self-evident that I should be able to sell anything at any price I like if there is an interested buyer. On the other hand, this seems like blatant tax fraud.

You can make a fat finger error on an online exchange, nobody will accuse you of avoiding taxes. But what if you sell at a low price to a relative or a friend? Even if this relative or friend immediately sells the asset at the market value, with progressive taxes and other non-linearities of the tax system, the government will get less money in the end.

If possible, I would like an answer for any particular jurisdiction, preferably a European one. If not, I am still curious to see what is your personal moral opinion.

Comment: The money you lose by selling below market value will be more than the money you save on taxes. Don't lose sight of the goal.

Comment: @PeteBecker True, but what if my goal is for my father to have a nice retirement?

Comment: The difference between fair market value and actual selling price would be a "gift", subject to gift taxes.

Comment: Also I expect that you would still have to pay tax on the real profit you made before you gave the bitcoin away.

Comment: Also personal moral opinions are off topic.

Comment: This is similar to the fallacious reasoning one might use when declining a raise or bonus because of the taxes they'll have to pay. It's virtually impossible to lower your gross income and have your after-tax income go up. Avoiding taxes by avoiding income is not a good strategy - you could live tax-free if you never make any money.

Comment: When transacting at non-fair value, with people you have some type of relationship with, there will be gift tax consequences that will vary widely between countries. Since you selected Germany, you can read up on German gift tax laws here: https://www.rosepartner.de/en/gift-tax-lawyer-lawfirm-germany.html#:~:text=The%20tax%20burden%20in%20the,tax%2Dfree%20amount%3A%20500%2C000%20euros

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Is it seriously so hard to imagine that someone can care about other people? It is (perhaps not so) clearly written that the buyer would be a relative or friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within reason, that is possible. What exactly "reasonable" is, depends on your specific tax laws

However it makes no sense. If you sell for 10.000 € and pay 50% tax on the profit so you end up with 5.500 € in your pocket. If you sell it at 1.000 € you pay no taxes but you end up with only 1.000 € in your pocket and a really really happy buyer.

Comment: The idea is that the buyer is someone you want to help. In your example, if I wanted to give my parents 5.500 €, I could sell the asset and give them the gains minus tax. However, since my parents are in a lower tax bracket, let's say 20%, I can sell the asset to THEM for 3.125 €, they sell it at market and make 6.875 € profit which is 5.500 € after tax. The only party not happy is the state, which received less tax. I should have made that more explicit.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik I believe Germany has gift tax, doesn't it?

Comment: In this case it may be better to gift the bitcoin to your parents. I believe the first 20,000 are tax free, So if you gift the bitcoin at the market value of 10,000, no tax is due at all. However it may be good to have a tax advisor look at this first

Comment: Germany does have gifttax but it depends massively on who is on the receiving end. For Child -> Parent its 20.000 tax free. For Parent -> child its 400.000 tax free